# Binding checkboxes to comma separated string in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have to bind the `checkboxes` on a page whose values match in a string containing comma separated values, i have done the opposite of this in jquery through map and join functions.
Its a combination of individual checkboxes on the page.

Comment: Its a collection of individual checkboxes like this  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="xyz" class="checkbox" id="chbServiceDue" runat="server" checked="checked" />

Comment: yah why am I not getting the checkmark? Did you not see what I put? Did you mean "state" or two-way binding? If just attaching state based on arr, I got that, holmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
  var arr = [4,6,2,7,2];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('.checkbox[value=' + arr[i] + ']').prop('checked',true);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Just to add, use quotes if the arr is string array. $('.checkbox[value="' + arr[i] + '"]').prop('checked',true);